# Plotly Text Annotation shows the same text throughout

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to show the text on the bars based on some filtered data but the text shows the same value for the last item in the list. I can't seem to find out what the issue is because `display_texts` itself gives me what I expect

```
filtered_data = df[df["Year"] == 2017]
display_texts = filtered_data["column_name"].tolist()

fig = px.bar(
        filtered_data,
        x="x_column",
        y="y_column",
        color="color",
        title="some title",
    )

fig.update_traces(
        texttemplate=display_texts,
        textposition="outside",
    )
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=1800, height=600)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove  `texttemplate=display_texts` and add `text=display_texts` to `px.bar`.